# The application stopped

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Good day. I have three java class in my android program. Before I added the 3rd class the application doesn't stopped but then right now when I already have my 3rd class and when I run it, the play button on my first class suddenly stops. There are no errors in my program though. Here is the code for my 3rd class.

```
package com.example.fillmeapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class App3Activity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main3);

}

}
```

Comment: have you delcared that class in the menifest

Comment: have you added `App3Activity` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: Can you show your manifest and layout?

Comment: Always start with the stacktrace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

You must add the `App3Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Hope Your first activity got destroyed. Kindly go through the android Activity lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the activity in the manifest. Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".App3Activity" />
```

Comment: i already added the 3rd activity to my android manifest but still it stopped anyway thank you :))